# Navigate Between Projects in Xcode 4.0

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm finally starting to get over my initial frustrations with Xcode 4.0 (why on earth did they think changing all of the keyboard shortcuts was a good idea).

However, one simple task is beyond me right now... how do I switch between multiple open projects via the keyboard?

For example, I have two different Xcode projects open, and the mac will put them both into the same Xcode application (unlike Windows where you can easily see multiple instances of the same application open).  I want to quickly toggle back and forth between these projects without going to Window -> (choose the other project).  Is there an easy keyboard shortcut for this?  It seems that there used to be.

Comment: Which version of XCode are u using Matt? It is the CMD + backticks (`) for me in XCode 4.2 so not tilde.

Answer (score 73):

To switch use following Keyboard shortcut
<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>

Comment: In case you don't know like me what tilde key is? Its ~ key, first in numeric keys row.

Answer (score 13):

Command + tilde("~") keys. Can be very useful when you have limited screen space.

Answer (score 1):

- Xcode 4.6 Italian Keyboard

  <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Furthermore, XCode windows must not be "maximized" (the icon with two arrows up on the right), otherwise the key shortcut has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 8.3.3 - German Keyboard

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd>

Update:

In fact there is a keybinding in Xcode that overides the system wide shortcut to switch between windows on german keyboards. The keybinding is <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd> for ***Scheme > Edit Scheme***.

When this shortcut is changed or removed, then the usual shortcuts to cycle through the open windows of an application will work as expected (i.e. <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd> cycle forward, <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd> cycle backward).

Comment: Danish MacBook Pro Keyboard too :)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>´</kbd>