# Navigate Between Projects in Xcode 7

Tags: xcode, xcode7, keyboard-shortcuts

What keyboard shortcut can be used to navigate between open projects in Xcode 7?

Have seen these suggestions ([[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415588/xcode-cycle-through-open-windows), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506040/is-there-a-shortcut-to-switch-between-windows-in-xcode), [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582629/navigate-between-projects-in-xcode-4-0)) for prior releases of Xcode, none seem to work in v7:

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd>.

Comment: Make each open project full screen and use OS X 's built in fast application switching. On track pad 3 finger swipe left or right to next previous. 3 finger swipe up goes to mission control and select from top of screen.

Comment: Cmd + ` is working fine for me on Xcode 7.3, although it appears the project  windows have to be in the same "space" (and not minimised) in order for it work.

Comment: @originaluser2 - doesn't work for me.. maybe it's because I'm on a laptop with a single key for ~`

Comment: @MarcusLeon Try going into System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Keyboard and seeing what you have defined for "Move focus to the next window"

Comment: It's Cmd + `  ....  not sure why it's not working.

Comment: Cmd + ` won't work if Xcode is full screen.

Comment: @AaronBrager - thanks that's it.  Guess the answer is Cmd + ` when not full screen and three finger swipe (@Bamsworld's answer) when in full screen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per the comments the answer here is to use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> when Xcode is not maximized, otherwise you can use [3 finger drag](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204895).

Thanks to @AaronBrager and @Bamsworld.

Comment: This still seems to be the solution in Xcode 12

Answer (score 3):

System Preferences->Keyboard->Shortcuts->Keyboard->√ Move focus to next window.

then, use Cmd + `